# Algebra extension of modules question

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

Let $M$ be an extension of modules of $A$ by $B$ (modules), i.e. $A \leqslant M$ and $M/A \cong B$. Show that if $M$ is finitely generated then so is $B$.

In the solution it just says: If $M = XR$ then $B = π(X)R$ where $π : M → B$ is the quotient map - is this intuitive? I can't see it.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M=XR$ which means that every elements can be written by $R$ combination of $X$.

Now, Let $b\in B$ then there exist an $m\in M$ such that $\pi(m)=b$. We know that 
$$m=r_1x_1+...+r_nx_n$$
$$b=\pi(m)=r_1\pi(x_1)+...r_n\pi(x_n)$$

So we see that any element of $b$ can be written as $R$ combiantion of $\pi(X)$.

Thus, $B=\pi(X)R$ and by finiteness of $X$, we are done.

Comment: How do we know that $b=\pi(m)=r_1\pi(x_1)+...r_n\pi(x_n)$?

Comment: @jemima: $\pi :M\mapsto B$ is an $R$ homomorphism i.e $\pi(rx)=r\pi(x)$ where $r\in R$

Comment: Please check the part homomorphism of modules http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)

Comment: Ah of course, thanks!